# Which port is used to access NAS device on network through file explorer?

Tags: networking, port, vpn, nas

I have two NAS devices attached on my network. I have both these devices mapped as network drive to laptop. So, when I am on my network (in my office premises) then I can access those drive without any hassle, however, when I try to access from any different network (from home), it doesn't get connected. I can be on my office network from my home using VPN certificate. Now, I believe that I can access those NAS devices from my home using VPN certificate, if I whitelist the **NAS IP and required PORT** in my VPN certificate. The problem is I don't know which port is used for this purpose. So, Can somebody may please tell me which port is used to access NAS Devices on network through file explorer??
[image]

Comment: check samba ports

Comment: @vidal My WD EX4100  NAS device is using SMB2 protocol. How do I check samba ports ( i am new)?

Comment: Does the VPN ip range is the in same segment of the "shared drives" does the bridge between those 2 networks also allow port 445?

Comment: Yes, it does allow. And IP is also in range.

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out in a comment, the NAS-devices use **SMBv2**. 
The protocol uses port **TCP 445** (see https://www.netify.ai/resources/protocols/smbv23).

Comment: Hi @Na1k, I have already tried ports 139 and 445 but these ports are not working for my problem, though, thanks for efforts.